# PHP multi-step registration process no username

Tags: php

I am working on a registration form which comprises of 2 total forms.

However, I have just realised that I am unable to retrieve data from the previous form (ie: at form 2 I am unable to retrieve the Username from Step 1 when i click submit on form 2). Instead i only get only detail from the last page (form 2) which are :

Array

```
[password] => Greatness
[fname] => John
[lname] => Winfield
[submit] =>
```

The array comes up like this and i dont get the username. I am an upcoming developer  please someone help me out tell me what to do, i'd be really greatful.

Comment: You can store the data of form 1 in Session, then retrieve form 1' data from Session when you handle form 2.

Comment: Please post your code here

Answer (score 0):

Ur extremely close. All u need to do now is:

1. insert the link of your form2 page in form1 action attribute. (this sends page data from form1 page to form2 page)
2. define the attribute method as post or get in form1. (which makes form1 inputs accessible in form2 page via POST or GET variables using php.

Not sure if u were wondering this too, but u can even auto-populate form2 w/ form1 inputs by embedding php w/in ur form 2 value attributes:

```
         ex)   <input type='text' value= "<?= $_POST['username']?>">
```